# iPhone keyboard language changes unintentionally

Tags: iphone, keyboard, language

I have this obnoxious problem for last 2 years since I bought my first iPhone in 2020 (iPhone 12). I use English as well as Hindi in my native keyboard. Going to emoji layout and coming back again to alphabets switches the languages to Hindi from English, of course not on purpose.

This happens only when no emoji is selected. For example, if I go to emoji panel, realise I want to write some more words before putting an emoji, and come back to alphabets layout, the language is changed.

This triggers only around 50% of the times. I am tired of switching back to English again and again, several times a day.

Searched a lot about this problem on internet but did not find someone having similar question or problem, let alone the solution.

Kindly help if someone has overcome this issue or know the possible cause of this.